# Add jQuery mouseover event to element

Tags: jquery, html

The HTML below has a simple image tag with the class `service_img`.

```
<img class="service_img" src="img/other/wedding.png" alt="wedding" />
```

This is the JavaScript code that I wrote:

```
$('.service_img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('animated jello');
})
```

How do I add a jQuery mouseover event to the `img`?

Comment: Please try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34331265/4763793

Comment: A simple google search will give you the link for this. https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Runs when the mouse enters the element
$("img.service_img").on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).addClass('animated jello');
});

// Runs when the mouse leaves the element
$("img.service_img").on('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('animated jello');
});
```